# How to represent hit count with Domain Driven Design

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

Let's say the context is a Job Portal website.

I have a requirement which says something like this :

> When a JobSeeker views a Vacancy, the Vacancy's view count is
>   incremented

How do I represent this in a web?

As far as I can think, it depends on which controller that requested the Vacancy, perhaps something like this:

```
class VacancyController {
    public function viewVacancy($vacancyId) {
        $vacancy = $this->repo->find($vacancyId);

        $vacancy->incrementView();

        $this->repo->persist($vacancy);

        return $vacancy;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to represent such rule in the Domain Layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update view count synchronously is not a good idea, especially when using RDBMS database.

```
update vacancy_view set 
    count = count + 1
where vacancy_id = $id
```

The row may get blocked if a lot of users view same vacancy within a short period of time.

I'd suggest use "inserting" instead. The inserting could be synchronous or asynchronous, depends on benchmark. But this implementation details could be hidden behind the applicationEvents abstraction. The view count could be sum up whenever it is requested or cached, in this use case, eventual consistency is usually tolerated.

```
class VacancyController {
    public function viewVacancy($vacancyId) {
        $vacancy = $this->repo->find($vacancyId);

        $this->applicationEvents->raise(VacancyViewedEvent($vacancyId))

        return $vacancy;
    }
}
```

It is said some nosql databases(such as Cassandra) fit well in view counting scenario, but I don't have experience with that yet.

Comment: Well for persistence, it's currently MongoDB. Can you give an example of application events implementation? Regarding to DDD context, can this be applied on the domain? Thanks

Comment: Just insert a doc if you adopt synchronous "inserting" approach. You could publish the event to messaging infrastructure or just delegate to another thread if you want to do it asynchronously. IMHO, you don't have to apply ddd with this use case. It's just a query, neither invariants need to be protected nor complex domain calculation involved.

Comment: Is threading can be done in PHP? I see your point, and it does seems appealing. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with php cocurrent model. You may ignore the threading part if it is not common in your platform. I just checked [NOSQL distilled](http://www.amazon.co.uk/NoSQL-Distilled-Emerging-Polyglot-Persistence/dp/0321826620), the authors recommend MongoDB also for page view count as one can update a document partially. So your original approach may work well without blocking issues(I guess MongoDB doesn't have some internal lock/latch when updating while RDBMS do). Cheers.

Comment: PHP typically uses a 'share-nothing' architecture, where each web request is handled in one separate thread and there is no communication between threads. So we don't hand tasks off directly to other threads.

What we usually do instead is use add a message to a queue outside the process when want work done asynchronously. A separate PHP process, often on a separate server picks up the message and does the work.